# Limiting access to Policyd

Tags: 14.04, email, policy, zimbra

I have a virtual machine installed with Ubuntu 14.04. I have Zimbra 8.5 installed on it.

I apparently do not have a way to prevent spammers who get access to an email account to prevent 1 million spam emails to be sent through this account either.

I read I can use Policyd to control this. I installed Policyd per [these instructions](https://imanudin.net/2014/09/08/how-to-install-policyd-on-zimbra-8-5/) and accessed the webpage without any problems.

I was suprised to see the webpage is open to the world. I thought it would require a login but I got straight into it. I don't see where I can add users to access it either.

How do I keep people out of it until I learn a little more about it. Last thing I need is someone making changes to my system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

according to that site, it will not be accessible if you try to reach it from the outside server and do not have it port mapped in your router. You can list that port to be refused after the configuration changes or just simply uninstall the web ui after making changes.

Comment: I just ended up blocking the port for now. Ty for the idea.

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to webui symlink and create a file that contains this:

**../webui/.htaccess**

```
AuthType Basic
AuthName "PolicyD"
AuthUserFile https://imanudin.net/2014/09/08/how-to-install-policyd-on-zimbra-8-5/.htpasswd
Require valid-user
```

2. Generate a password with `htpasswd <password>`
3. Create a .htpasswd file

**../webui/.htpasswd**

```
 user:<output of htpasswd>
```